# Работа с относительными единицами

Tags: css

Всем привет! На днях приобрел книгу `Css - для профи "Кит Грант"`. 
Книга вроде ничего, 2019г, много полезного и интересного материала, особенно для человека, который только пытается вливаться в эту профессию! Но у меня есть вопрос, прочитав первые 50 страниц, дошел до темы "Работа с относительными единицами", так вот, он советует отвыкать от px и переходить на em, все примеры в книге он приводит именно на этих единицах. Как быть? Читать книгу и делать все на px или же освоить единицы?

Comment: освоить всегда есть смысл, пригодится. А чем пользоваться удобнее в каждом конкретном случае, потом для себя определитесь сами.

Comment: Спасибо, но я понимаю, что делать размеры на px намного проще чем высчитывать все на em... Вы бы что посоветовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Освоить единицы и использовать по ситуации всё.

Навскидку пример совместной работы пикселей и em'ов:

- Вам нужны два набора кнопок с разным размером шрифта.
- В первом наборе вам нужно, чтобы сохранялись РАЗМЕРЫ кнопок.
- Во втором - чтобы сохранялись ПРОПОРЦИИ кнопок.

Вот (для сравнения еще набор кнопок по умолчанию):

```css
button {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.small {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.medium {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.big {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.set1 button {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.set2 button {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
Всё по умолчанию. Паддинги в пикселах, пропорции кнопок разные:
<div class="set0"><button class="small">Кнопка</button> <button class="medium">Кнопка</button> <button class="big">Кнопка</button></div>
<hr> Задана высота и ширина в пикселах. Кнопки одинаковых габаритов, текст разный:
<div class="set1"><button class="small">Кнопка</button> <button class="medium">Кнопка</button> <button class="big">Кнопка</button></div>
<hr> Заданы паддинги в em'ах. Кнопки имеют одинаковые пропорции:
<div class="set2"><button class="small">Кнопка</button> <button class="medium">Кнопка</button> <button class="big">Кнопка</button></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я постараюсь разобраться с этим!